# Undocumented error with LinkedIn oAuth API

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

I have a user using my application which implements a social signin using LinkedIn oAuth API.

The error returned is:

**invalid_request**

and the error description is:

**error retrieving consumer** ***xxxxxxxx***

Where I've shown xxx appears to be a unique LinkedIn identifier for the user.

I've had no other users report this problem, have been unable to replicate it, and Google matches nothing.

Any ideas? LinkedIn do not have an error reference document, so it's quite difficult to track down what might be going wrong.

Comment: Can you share the specific call you're making?  That error indicates something isn't properly formatted in your request, but without the request to look at, it's hard to help.

Comment: I hadn't shared the specific code as it appears to work fine for other users. The particular user that reported this error said it happened several times before he was able to connect. Neither he, nor us have been able to reproduce the error since. My suspicion was that it was a temporary LinkedIn problem? The error was returned from LinkedIn as a response to a request to get an authorization code.